# Construct nested JSON value in sql/json (Oracle Database)

Tags: sql, json, database, oracle, serialization

How do I construct a JSON value with a nested JSON value as a serialized string?  I tried this:

```
SQL>  select json { 'y' : json_serialize(json('{"hello":"world"}')) } x
      from dual;  

X
--------------------------------------------------------------------
{"y":{"hello":"world"}}
```

But the result I want is:

```
{"y":"{\"hello\":\"world\"}"}
```

I'm using Oracle Database 20c.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON object constructor recognizes the output of `json_serialize` as serialized JSON and converts it to a JSON value when constructing the outer object.  Use `to_clob()` instead:

```
select json { 'y' : to_clob(json('{"hello":"world"}')) } x
from dual;
```